# Get the rest of String after a token has been retrieved

Tags: c, string, token, getline

Assume I have the following function:

```
void readcmd(char* cmd, char* params) {
  char* input;
  size_t size = 0;
  char* sep = "\t\v\r\f\n\b "; // separator

  getline(&input, &size, stdin);
  cmd = strtok(input, sep);
}
```

And my input is:

*I like Stackoverflow!*

In the code above, I've made my program store the first token in *cmd* array. I want the rest of the sentence to be stored in params array; thus:

cmd: *I*

params: *like Stackoverflow!*

How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: It's as well to make sure that `input = 0;` — safety first — even though the specification of `getline()` says: _The application shall ensure that `*lineptr` is a valid argument that could be passed to the `free()` function. If `*n` is non-zero, the application shall ensure that `*lineptr` either points to an object of size at least `*n` bytes, or is a null pointer._  You shouldn't pass an uninitialized pointer to `free()`, so you shouldn't pass (the address of) an uninitialized pointer to `getline()`.  You also need to `free(input)` before returning.

Comment: Also, since you don't know how much space `params` points to, you can't safely copy the residue of the line into `params`.  Similarly with `cmd`; you can't tell how big a command name is safe.  I suggest upgrading your function to have the signature `void readcmd(char *cmd, size_t cmdlen, char *params, size_t paramslen)`.  Also, you don't check for errors (`getline()` returns `-1`, not EOF, incidentally), and you have no way to report that an error occurred (unless setting one or both strings to empty can be used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after processing comments, a more complete example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void readcmd(char** cmd, char** params) {
  char* input = 0;
  size_t size = 0;
  char* sep = "\t\v\r\f\n\b "; // separator

  if (getline(&input, &size, stdin) < 0) {
    printf("failed to read a line\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  *cmd = strtok(input, sep);

  if (*cmd) {
    *cmd = strdup(*cmd);
    *params = strdup(input + strlen(input) + 1);
  }
  free(input);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char *cmd = 0;
  char *params = 0;

  readcmd(&cmd, &params);

  if (cmd) {
    printf("cmd: %s\n", cmd);
    free(cmd);
  }
  if (params) {
    printf("params: %s\n", params);
    free(params);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'd have to split the command from the parameters, perhaps with `strtok_r()` or `strtok_s()`, or maybe using `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()`. You'd probably then put a null byte at the separation point. Then `*params = input + strlen(cmd);` would point at the null byte; you need `*params = input + strlen(cmd) + 1;`. Note that if you have to skip leading white space from the input, then the return value would not be passable to `free()`, yet if you don't `free()` what is returned, you leak. Is it better to `strdup()` the strings: `*params = strdup(input + strlen(input) + 1);` and `free(input);`?

Comment: "*about something*" is a bit vage. Also the result of your proposed snippet might not return what the OP expects, as it will be pointing to `'\0'`.

Comment: This has solved my question with @JonathanLeffler help. Thank you very much!

Comment: The modified snippet will invoke undefined behaviour in case none of the seperators in `sep` will be found in `input`!

Comment: This still will invoke UB, if none of the seperators in `sep` will be found in `input`, as `input + strlen(input) + 1` will point "0 bytes after" `input`.

Comment: yes, that's what the `if (*cmd) {` is supposed to check so `strlen(input) + 1` would not be called for that case

Comment: But it doesn't. Assume `input` to be `"abc"` and re-test. You can achieve this by entering `abc` and finishing input via pressing`Ctrl-D` (or `Ctrl-Z` on Windows) instead of `Enter`.

Comment: Also this line `free(input);` does not makes sense as it invalidates what will be passed up via `*cmd`.

Comment: Sry, but you didn't. Please re-test as I proposed.